# POST/POLL/GET with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, get, polling

How can I use python submit an image (a URL link to an image) to an API, poll for job completion and get the results from the finished job (another image)? What are some steps I could take to do this? I have a username and password for the API as well.

Comment: It looks like any number of tutorials would cover at least part of this. Have you searched for any? For example, if it's a RESTful API you might search for "python rest client tutorial" or "python http".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library. It contains all of the info you need for [authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication) as well as making [POST and GET requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request), provided you have the documentation for the API you want to use